# How to exclude part of string starting and ending with specific word/character in Regex?

Tags: regex

Trying to basically edit the JSON file using grep and currently I have

```
(?={\"expand)(.*?)(?= @)|(?=","component)(.*?)(?<=}})
```

This is to look at the string and exclude any string that comes after "@" and before the string ""component"(quotation before the word).
When I use this I just keep getting the first part (everything before "@" but not the strings after ""component")

I've been searching everywhere but the solution that was posted applies to texts that have multiple strings but this JSON file is considered one giant whole string so they didn't work.

Already tried regex such as:

```
(?<!"component\.)$
```

Comment: I didn't really understand in what environment are you trying to use the regex. Anyways, can you please provide an example input and expected output? It would be much easier to understand

Comment: Why not use a json library of some kind? Or [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you are doing this from the command line. Using regex for any structured format is error prone.

Comment: Is the value you're trying to edit only a key or also a value? I'd seriously consider parsing the json instead.

Comment: Im trying to use this with grep. Example input would be:{"expand":sometexthere@"notwantedtexthere","component":moretexthere} and output would be: {"expand":sometexthere,"component":moretexthere} @SeanBright I am using jq right now but is there some way to filter output like that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some actual JSON data?

Comment: Just added them

Comment: I humbly suggests you'd use another method for parsing structured data (e.g. JSON), just like @SeanBright explained

Comment: Assuming it's always the `summary` property: `jq '.fields.summary |= sub(" *@.*"; "")' your_json_file.json`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: Is it possible to remove this post? When i try it just refreshes and cant seem to delete it

Comment: Yes im using mobile but im on the browser. Ill try again on my desktop